# Trying to find upper bounds when proving limits by definition

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to prove in terms of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition that

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (2,3)} y \sin(xy - 6) = 0$$

But I'm struggling trying to find an upper bound for $\mid y \sin(xy - 6)\mid$. I've tried to rewrite it in terms of $\mid (y-3)\sin(xy-6) +3\sin(xy-6) \mid$, but then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You could just apply the general results that the sum  anf the product of continuous function is continuous, and if if $f,g$ are continuous then the function h(p)=f(g(p)) is continuous on its domain.

Comment: Use the fact that $|\sin\, t| \leq |t|$.

Answer (score 1):

(i). Let  $0< a<1.$

For $|x-2|<a$  and $|y-3|<a$ let $x=2+b$ and $y=3+c.$ Then:

(ii). $|b|<a>|c|$ and $|bc|<a^2< a.$

(iii). $|y|\le 3+|c|<3+a<4.$

(iv). $|xy-6| = |(2+b)(3+c)-6|=|3b+2c+bc| \le |3b|+|2c|+|bc|<3a+2a+a=6a.$

(v). $|\sin (xy-6)|\le |xy-6|<6a$ by (iv).

(vi). $|y\sin (xy-6)=|y|\cdot |\sin (xy-6)|<4 \cdot 6a=24a.$

Therefore for $\epsilon >0$ take $0<a<1$ such that, also, $a<\epsilon /24.$ Then $$(|x-2|<a\land |y-3|<a)\implies |y\sin (xy-6)|<24a<\epsilon.$$